# Why does XML::Twig output the extracted string twice?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

Why do I get my string two times in the output?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Twig;


my $string = '<cd_catalogue><title>Hello, World!</title></cd_catalogue>';

my $t= XML::Twig->new(  twig_handlers   => { cd_catalogue => \&cd_catalogue, },
            pretty_print => 'indented', 
);

$t->parse( $string );


sub cd_catalogue {
    my( $t, $cd_catalogue ) = @_;
    $cd_catalogue->flush;
}


# Output:
#<cd_catalogue>
#  <title>Hello, World!</title>
#</cd_catalogue>
#<cd_catalogue>
#  <title>Hello, World!</title>
#</cd_catalogue>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing your sub to use `print` and `purge` instead of `flush` gets around problem:

```
sub cd_catalogue {
    my( $t, $cd_catalogue ) = @_;
    $cd_catalogue->print;
    $cd_catalogue->purge;
}
```

The `flush` is getting confused because of the simplicity of your example because `cd_catalogue` is root node.  If you change your data to something like this:

```
my $string = '
    <cds>
        <cd_catalogue><title>Hello, World!</title></cd_catalogue>
    </cds>';
```

or if you changed your twig_handler to look for `title`:

```
twig_handlers    => { title => \&cd_catalogue }
```

then you will find that `$cd_catalogue->flush` now works as expected with your `$string`.

/I3az/

Answer (score 4):

Your program uses XML::Twig incorrectly. [According to the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm), you should "always flush the twig, not an element."

Change `cd_catalogue` to

```
sub cd_catalogue {
    my( $t, $cd_catalogue ) = @_;
    $t->flush;
}
```

to get the expected behavior.

Comment: Strangely this is what I put originally in my answer :) However the documentation does say and also provides examples of using flush with "elements" (http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm#Processing_an_XML_document_chunk_by_chunk).

Comment: yes, flushing on an element flushes up to that element, I will fix the docs. Thanks